# How can I set up a JFrame button to open another JFrame, and then receive information once the second jframe is closed?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

This is part of a project for school, and I'm stuck and need someone to bounce ideas off of.  I have a game where there is an option to sign up or sign in for a machine-local game so a record can be kept of the person's scores.  The game is run from a base GUI JFrame, and I want to make buttons to bring up secondary windows for the person to sign in or sign up, before closing out of them.  I need to pass the validated username back to the initial GUI/game class so I can store it for the following game so the game score can be added under that user.  I just need to pass the username back and I'm not sure how to go about it.  This is the main GUI code up to where I'm having my issue:

```
public class MathFactsGUI extends JFrame
{

// instance variables
private JTextField problemJTextField, answerJTextField;
private JLabel equalJLabel;
private JButton  additionJButton, multiplicationJButton;
private JButton signupJButton, signinJButton; 
private JButton submitJButton;
private JLabel scoreJLabel,resultJLabel;
//private JButton reviewButton;
private String username;
private Userbase userbase;
private JLabel introJLabel;
Quiz quiz;

/**
 * Constructor for objects of class MathFactsGUI
 */
public MathFactsGUI()
{
    super("Math Facts Quiz");

    userbase = Userbase.getUserbase();
    username = "guest";
    /* code here has been removed to be abbreviated */

   // Action listener for buttons
    additionJButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
           quiz = new Quiz('+');
           problemJTextField.setText(quiz.getCurrentProblem());
           additionJButton.setEnabled(false);
           multiplicationJButton.setEnabled(false);
           signupJButton.setEnabled(false);
           signinJButton.setEnabled(false);
        }            
    }); 

    multiplicationJButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
           quiz = new Quiz('x');
           problemJTextField.setText(quiz.getCurrentProblem());
           additionJButton.setEnabled(false);
           multiplicationJButton.setEnabled(false);
           signupJButton.setEnabled(false);
           signinJButton.setEnabled(false);
        }            
    });

    signinJButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            JDialo
        }

    });

    signupJButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
           
            MathFactsSignUpGUI signUpGUI = new MathFactsSignUpGUI();
            gui.setVisible(true);
        
        }
    });
}
```

This is the `JFrame` I wrote for the sign-up button:

````
public class MathFactsSignUpGUI extends JDialog {
    private JTextField usernameJTextField, userPassJTextField, userFirstNameJTextField;
    private JLabel usernameJLabel, userPassJLabel, userFirstNameJLabel;
    private JButton  submitJButton;
    private String username;
    private String userPass;
    private String userFirstName;

    public MathFactsSignUpGUI(){
        usernameJLabel = new JLabel("Username:");
        usernameJTextField = new JTextField();

        userPassJLabel = new JLabel("Password:");
        userPassJTextField = new JTextField();

        userFirstNameJLabel = new JLabel("Player First Name:");
        userFirstNameJTextField = new JTextField();

        Box usernameBox = Box.createHorizontalBox();
        usernameBox.add(usernameJLabel);
        usernameBox.add(usernameJTextField);

        Box userPassBox = Box.createHorizontalBox();
        userPassBox.add(userPassJLabel);
        userPassBox.add(userPassJTextField);

        Box userFirstBox = Box.createHorizontalBox();
        userFirstBox.add(userFirstNameJLabel);
        userFirstBox.add(userFirstNameJTextField);

        submitJButton = new JButton("Submit");
        submitJButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                username = usernameJTextField.getText();
                userPass = userPassJTextField.getText();
                userFirstName = userFirstNameJTextField.getText();

                if (!checkValid(username) || !checkValid(userPass) || !checkValid(userFirstName)){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "All fields must have values.");
                } else if (Userbase.getUserbase().userExist(username)==true){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Username is taken, please choose another.");
                } else {
                    Userbase.getUserbase().addUser(username, new User(username, userPass, userFirstName));
                    MathFactsGUI.setUsername(username);
                }
            }
        });

        JPanel mfSignUp = new JPanel()
        mfSignUp.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));
        mfSignUp.add(usernameBox);
        mfSignUp.add(userPassBox);
        mfSignUp.add(userFirstBox);
        mfSignUp.add(submitJButton);
    }

    public String signIn(){
        return username;
    }

    public boolean checkValid(String a){
        if (a == null || a.length() == 0){
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}```
````

I was thinking of implementing a `WindowListener` action for when the sign-up/sign-in frames close, but I'm not sure that will work.  I was also looking into `JDialog`, but I'm not sure if it has the layout/text verification properties I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `JOptionPane`. It will simplify your layout without the need for creating a separate `JFrame` and easily pass values back to wherever it was called from. You can then make it check for valid username when you click OK.

[Try this site. It gives a good rundown with example images](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-joptionpane)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to understand that this is an object, so you can create some global variables which will contains this information(username,password,Nickname), i recommend to pull info from MathFactsSignUpGUI  by using ScheduledExecutorService. It will  pull info from this sign up gui in every 100ms, than it will destroy itself, here is an example:

```
MathFactsSignUpGUI su = new MathFactsSignUpGUI ();
        su.setVisible(true);
        ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        service.schedule(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                if(!su.username.isEmpty() && !su.userPass.isEmpty() && !su.userFirstName.isEmpty() ){
                    if(su.isLogin){ //if player is loggining
                        //do something here
                    }else{//if user is registered
                        //do something here
                    }
                    System.out.println("Check complete");
                    service.shutdown();//to destroy this service after recieving the data
                }
            }
        }, 100, TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS);
```